# Do not understand why this expression isn't inner product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> See as follows: "Verify why $\langle p, q \rangle = \int_{a}^{b} p(x)q(x)dx $
> isn't an inner product in $C(\mathbb R)$ (space of continuous functions from $\mathbb R$
> to $\mathbb R$), even so it is an inner product in $C([a,b])$, where $a,b \in\mathbb  R$".

Now, I am a little confused to understand why it can be written as an inner product in $C(\mathbb R)$.

I mean, there is essentially three conditions an inner product need to satisfy, right?

**Linearity** - the integral itself is linear, so it is already satisfied.

**Conjugate symmetric** - since we are in real functions space, the conjugate of a functions is itself, and since the product of functions commute, $\langle p,q\rangle=\langle q,p\rangle$ as well.

**Positive definiteness**
$$\int_{k}^{j} f(x)f(x)dx = \lim_{i\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}   f(x_{i})f(x_{i})(k-j)/\Delta n,$$
$$\Delta n>0, f(x_{i})f(x_{i}) = f(x_{i})^2 >0,$$ so the sum is  greater than zero.
$$\lim_{i\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}   f(x_{i})f(x_{i})(k-j)/\Delta n = 0 $$
is equivalent to "find $a,b,\dots,n$ such that $a^2 + b^2 + \dots + n^2 = 0$, which implies $a=b=c=....=n=0$, so the integral is zero only if $f$ is zero.

So what is the problem? Why can't it be an inner product?

Comment: If $f(x)=1,$ what is $\langle f, f\rangle?$

Comment: What does $a,b>\epsilon R$ mean?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski a, b, i forgot it. it is ALready edited now

Comment: @ThomasAndrews someone edited my question and put this >. I already took it off. It should means belong to real.

Comment: It is not an inner product because vanishing of $p$ on $[a,b]$ does not guarantee that it venishes on the whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a function $f$ which is $0$ in $[a,b]$ has $\langle f,f\rangle =0,$ even if it is non-zero outside $[a,b].$

For example $f(x)=|x-a| + a-x$ is zero of $x\geq a$ and non-zero for $x<a.$

What you showed was that $f(x)$ is zero in $[a,b],$ but that is not the definition of $f=0$ in $C(\mathbb R).$